# Android How to Determine When Notification Sound Finishes Playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I attach a custom sound to my `Notification` like this:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + soundResId);
```

I can stop the player by canceling the `Notification`, but I want to know when the player finishes playing the custom sound.

I understand that you can monitor a sound played by the `MediaPlayer` with an `OnCompletionListener` if you have started the sound and have a `mediaPlayer` object.

But, how can I tell when my custom `Notification` sound finishes playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your sound file, so you know what the duration is. When your notification is being click you start a countdown timer and when the countdown timer end, then your notification sound finishes, give and take a few hundred microseconds.

Comment: or OP could be smarter about it and just set a completion listener rather than counting in milliseconds which is super hacky...

Comment: @SMT how does one set a completion listener on a Notification?